# How to write a regular expression for 5 scenarios of Date/Time?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am looking for a solution to regular expression that would take/accept 5 variations of Date/Time

- 01/01/2022
- 12:12:00
- Time: 12:12:00
- Date: 01/01/2022
- Date/Time: 01/01/2022 12:12:00

So far all I have working is the following: But the Date: ... and 01/01/2022 are no triggering. So far this is the best I could come up with the resources on the internet.

```
preg_match('/(^)?((date|time|(date(?:(?!\/time))?\/time))\:.)?(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})?(.)?(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})/')
```

This is not for date validation. This information has already been updated, and is only being selected. I needed to separate the values so incase one was stored 1 way on the record, and differently on another record. The purpose is to parse a record and turning it into an object. This question has been answered.

[https://onlinephp.io demo](https://onlinephp.io/?s=XY7LCsIwEEX3gfzDCIUmIk0bXdVHNn6AC3dWJWi0ItWQRkGs_26Tan1AFpdzZ85kJHSuMcIokMbMpLXKnGAMC4wAYhhPIEx46l_YcyxpWMwSznjM44ZyT6fSqhT-u77v5ofCdT-uQbvFXnW7-pnEaDnEaHc2Sm5yIN_flCUER3VzlkA3jMLdmbVR-3Uh7SYnISMrKgjZ1mcqW5-pfCQiJaKTMUcoFe-QpVE9HHUpOxRhr9XWydtUSYfOf5Vmvb0UmnzjB0ZP&v=8.1.7)

Comment: Regex doesn't seem to be the right tool for this.

Comment: Use a date/time parser instead.

Comment: What about the meta data, it is part of the parse ... I'm turning this into a quick object, and this will be parsed from a db->table. and stored quickly as a property. Apparently the criteria for that particular line is 5 different variants. (SOAP note) Fine, ill just look for the meta data, and store the value(s) as string, and parse them separately.

Comment: Your regex *requires* there is a time part. And even if you would solve that, it would accept invalid dates and invalid times... Regex is not the tool for this.

Comment: This its not for the date validation. Its a key =>value scenario so that I can use switch case scenario to guess what the value is... stored. Next Line.

Answer (score 0):

> - This is not for date validation.
> - regular expression that would take/accept 5 variations of Date/Time

Ok, so to capture and extract date and time strings, you can make your regex much simpler by:

- Stripping of `Date:`, `Time:`, `Date/Time:` using [`str_ireplace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). Now, we are only left with actual date and time values to match.
- Creating a regex to match a date format of `dd/mm/YYYY` as `\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}` and similarly for time as `HH:ii:ss` as `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`. Now, we perform optional matches for both groups using `?`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
        '01/01/2022',
        '12:12:00',
        'Time: 12:12:00',
        'Date: 01/01/2022',
        'Date/Time: 01/01/2022 12:12:00'
    ];
    
foreach($tests as $test){
    preg_match('/(Date\/Time|Time|Date)\:/', $test, $possible_metadata);
    $metadata = $possible_metadata[1] ?? "";
    var_dump($metadata);
    $test = trim(str_ireplace(['Date/Time:','Time:','Date:'],'', $test));
    preg_match('/^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})?\s*(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)?$/', $test, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/36f37)

Comment: This is a much better answer, but it doesn't solve one thing. The meta data is important for the record output. I needed to know which one it was, to know what the output is going to be Date/...: Was it blank or was named... Anyways thank your suggestion.

Comment: @BarryDick That sounds good. I have updated my answer for metadata as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a bit modular to perhaps extend it later on, you can specify [separate subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#define) using `(?(DEFINE)` and make the patterns for the date and the time a bit more specific.

Note that this will still not validate the date itself.

Then you can assemble the pattern with optional non capture groups for `Date:` etc, and the array key in the result will show for which variant there is a match.

As the alternation `|` tests for 3 variations, filter the result and keep the named group that has a value.

The `mxJ` flags at the end of the pattern stand for `multiline` as there are anchors, `extended` to enable the current regex notation and ignore whitespaces, and `J` to enable the duplicate sub pattern names like `dt`

```
$strings = [
    '01/01/2022',
    '12:12:00',
    'Time: 12:12:00',
    'Date: 01/01/2022',
    'Date/Time: 01/01/2022 12:12:00',
    'test 01/01/2024'
];

$re = '~(?(DEFINE)
  (?<d>\b(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?:19|20)\d\d)\b
  (?<t>\b(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d)\b
  (?<dt>(?&d)\h+(?&t))
)
^(?:(?:Date:\h*)?(?<d>(?&d))|(?:Time:\h*)?(?<t>(?&t))|(?:Date/Time:\h*)?(?<dt>(?&dt)))$~mxJ';

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
        $result = array_filter($matches, function ($v, $k) {
            return !(empty($v)) && !is_int($k);
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
        
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [d] => 01/01/2022
)
Array
(
    [t] => 12:12:00
)
Array
(
    [t] => 12:12:00
)
Array
(
    [d] => 01/01/2022
)
Array
(
    [dt] => 01/01/2022 12:12:00
)
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/813f1)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information previously gathered, the best route is to simply use:

```
preg_match('/(^)?((date|time|(date(?:(?!\/time))?\/time))\:)?(.*)/im');
```

That way in the 5th field will be the timestamp (date?/time), and in the  group 3 it will tell its name (Date/Time/Date-Time).

Comment: This looks incorrect. It even matches `dummy text`. See [demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/dcb8e)

Comment: I'm not looking for validation. I'm parsing the information. The first line says the date comes in 5 different ways, I need to look for each one. If it doesn't pass as a case, I don't care.

Comment: So you wish to capture/extract the date and time strings? If so, your regex could be much simpler.